# Merge local committed branch to a new branch, but uncommit the changes

Tags: git

I have a lot of locally modified files used for configs and testing on committed but not pushed *branch1*. I would like to create a new *branch2* *with* the changes from *branch1*, add new changes, then push *only* the new commit to master.  I have tried

```
git merge branch1 branch2
```

but it automatically adds the commit on *branch1* to *branch2* with my new commit. How do I achieve this in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do might be to just cherry pick the commit you just made in `branch1` over to your local `master` branch, and then just push `master` to the repository.  Something like this:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of new commit from branch1>
git push origin master
```

To find out what the `SHA-1` hash of the new `branch1` commit is, you can try switching to that branch and using `git log`:

```
git checkout branch1
git log
# now look for the SHA-1 hash of the commit appearing at the very top
```